# Distributing one sum on several invoices

Tags: algorithm, sorting, knapsack-problem

I have a task, it can be done in VB.net language or other programming languages as well. i'm just looking for an idea how it can be done

**Task description:**

Bank transfer comes to me, let's say on `10 000`. Now I have to find the combination of invoices that can be covered by this amount - and the total amount (`10 000`) will be fully allocated.

```
No Invoice| Value

Invoice 1 | 3000 
Invoice 2 | 1400
Invoice 3 | 9100
Invoice 4 | 1000
Invoice 5 | 8500
Invoice 6 | 900
```

For example, based on this case I would like to pay for `Invoice 3 (9100) + Invoice 6 (900) = 10 000`

I was trying to adjust this problem to knapsack algorithm or partition sort, but in my opinion it is too complex

Comment: Did you try my answer below? Is that something that helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly this is very much like Knapsack. The difference is that here the weight of the item is equal its value. So just a particular case of Knapsack. I went on geeksforgeeks and modified their algorithm a bit, here it is in c#:

```
using System ; 

class GFG { 

    // A utility function that returns 
    // maximum of two integers 
    static int max(int a, int b) 
    { 
        return (a > b) ? a : b; 
    } 

    // Prints the items which are put 
    // in a knapsack of capacity W 
    static void printknapSack(int W, int []wt, 
                            int []val, int n) 
    { 
        int i, w; 
        int [,]K = new int[n + 1,W + 1]; 

        // Build table K[][] in bottom up manner 
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) { 
            for (w = 0; w <= W; w++) { 
                if (i == 0 || w == 0) 
                    K[i,w] = 0; 
                else if (wt[i - 1] <= w) 
                    K[i,w] = Math.Max(val[i - 1] + 
                            K[i - 1,w - wt[i - 1]], K[i - 1,w]); 
                else
                    K[i,w] = K[i - 1,w]; 
            } 
        } 

        // stores the result of Knapsack 
        int res = K[n,W]; 
        Console.WriteLine(res); 

        w = W; 
        for (i = n; i > 0 && res > 0; i--) { 

            // either the result comes from the top 
            // (K[i-1][w]) or from (val[i-1] + K[i-1] 
            // [w-wt[i-1]]) as in Knapsack table. If 
            // it comes from the latter one/ it means 
            // the item is included. 
            if (res == K[i - 1,w]) 
                continue; 
            else { 

                // This item is included. 
                Console.Write(wt[i - 1] + " "); 

                // Since this weight is included its 
                // value is deducted 
                res = res - val[i - 1]; 
                w = w - wt[i - 1]; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    // Driver code 
    public static void Main() 
    { 
        int []val = { 3000, 1400, 9100, 1000, 8500, 900 }; 
        int []wt = { 3000, 1400, 9100, 1000, 8500, 900 }; 
        int W = 10000; 
        int n = val.Length; 

        printknapSack(W, wt, val, n); 
    } 
}
```

Running this code will give the output:

> 10000
>
> 900 9100

More details and explanations for the general problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/printing-items-01-knapsack/

Answer (score 0):

I have an example with recursive function in c#.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> invoices = new List<int> { 3000, 1400, 9100, 1000, 8500, 900};
        int totalAmount = 10000;
        List<int> rest = new List<int>();
        sum(invoices, totalAmount, rest);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void sum(List<int> invoices, int totalAmount, List<int> rest)
    {
        int currentSum = rest.Sum();

        if (currentSum == totalAmount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + totalAmount + " is reached with following values.");
            foreach (var restVal in rest)
                Console.WriteLine(restVal + ",");
        }


        if (currentSum >= totalAmount)
            return;

        for(int i=0; i<invoices.Count; i++)
        {
            int inv = invoices[i];
            List<int> firstPart = new List<int>();
            List<int> secondPart = new List<int>();

            firstPart.Add(invoices[i]);

            for (int j = i + 1; j < invoices.Count; j++)
                secondPart.Add(invoices[j]);

            firstPart = rest.Concat(firstPart).ToList();

            sum(secondPart, totalAmount, firstPart);
        }
    }
```

I think this is also close to knapsack algorithm and will be very costly for large dataset.